# How to use previous state properties in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to increment the `adult` property of `passenger` object from my store

```
const store = {
//...
passenger: {
    adult: 1,
    child: 0
  }
///...
}
```

In my reducer I have

```
if (action.type === actionTypes.ADD_ADULT) {
    return {
      ...state,
      adult: state.passenger.adult + 1
    };
  }
```

but of course I get a mistake "Cannot read property 'adult' of undefined", because official Redux documentation says *Redux will call reducer with an undefined state for the first time*. Is there a way to use previous state or should I just pass a new value of `adult` through `action.payload`?

P.S.: I am using `combineReducers` and `preloadedState`, if it impacts somehow.

Comment: Can you share your full reducer code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an `initialState` object that you use as default value for your state so that `state.adult` will have a value.

**Example**

```
const initialState = {
  adult: 0,
  child: 0
};
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === actionTypes.ADD_ADULT) {
    return {
      ...state,
      adult: state.adult + 1
    };
  }

  // ...

  else {
    return state;
  }
}
```